# The meaning of 強くあろうと意識した in this context

Tags: meaning, manga, japanese-to-english

Context: One character said to the MC that she only felt herself truly become strong since the day she met her Master. Then she said this to confirm that again (maybe?):

> **そのときからだな、強くあろうと意識したのは**

I'm not sure about the meaning of this sentence, my guesses are:

1. It must be from that day, that I'm aware of myself being strong
2. [.....], that I know I have to try to become strong

If my understanding was wrong, please help me understand the correct meaning! Thanks o/

---

*Edit*: forgot to add the full context so here it is:

MC wants to help the people in this world (he has been isekai'd and there's a war here)

Then he talked to this character (A-san), and A-san talking about the fact that she only felt herself truly become strong since the day she met her Master (T-sama).

> MC「A-sanは強そうだね」
>
> A-san「腕には昔から自信があったが、真に強くなれたと思えたのは、T-samaと出会ってからだな」
>
> MC 「それは？」
>
> A-san 「力を持つことの理由や使い方を示してくださったのがT-samaだ」
>
> A-san「ゆえに、私とBはT-samaのために戦い、夢を叶える後押しをしようと決めた」
> (B is her friend, T-sama's dream is to end war and bring true peace to everyone)
>
> **A-san「そのときからだな、強くあろうと意識したのは」 (>>here is the line I was wondering about)**

---

*Edit 2*: added the sentences following the bolded line:

> MC 「俺と同じだ」
>
> A-san 「自惚れるな。私はまだお前を完全に信用したわけではないからな」
>
> A-san 「……話が長くなってしまった。私も少し休ませてもらうとしよう」

Comment: I added some formatting and did some copy-editing. It makes a big difference for answerers/other readers of the question, so please review the edit to see my changes so you can use similar techniques in the future: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/93772/revisions

Answer (score 3):

Technically it is an inverted cleft sentence (I don't know this is the correct term).

Consider the non-inverted version: 強くあろうと意識したのはそのときからだな, which has the same structure as

- はじめてアメリカに行ったのは18歳の時です *It was when I was 18 years old that I went to the US for the first time*.

So the sentence should be translated as *It was since then that (I) 強くあろうと意識した.*

Now あろう here is ある + [う](https://www.kokugobunpou.com/%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E/%E3%81%86-%E3%82%88%E3%81%86/#gsc.tab=0), meaning *try to be(come)* and 意識する means something along the lines of "obj. is got awareness in subj's mind". So the whole phrase means literally *I got aware that I will try to be strong*. More idiomatically, it means *I started making conscious efforts to become strong*.

Cf. [A dictionary](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%84%8F%E8%AD%98-30519) has the following definition (closest would be ロ):

> ③ (━する) 何事かを気にとめること。
>
> (イ) 心に悟ること。わかること。また考えること。
>
> (ロ) ある意図をもってすること。
>
> (ハ) 自分やまわりのようすがどうなっているかに気づくこと。
>
> (ニ) 特別にある人や物事を気にかけること。

---

BTW, I think you could try to add a bit more of your current grammatical/lexical understanding, so that the question clarifies exactly what part of the sentence poses difficulty. I understand it is not always possible but just a suggestion.

Comment: I added the next sentences ,still confuse me as to why she say something like you pointed out above ,when she's already strong ??

Comment: @casualreader The preceding sentences suggest that she was strong physically, but didn't know 力を持つことの理由や使い方, which could be called spiritual strength (a common theme in bushido kind of thing). So the sentence in question means something like *since then I tried to reach mature/real/authentic strength just instead of being rampant*, depending on the character of A-san.

Answer (score 0):

There is another answer I got from a Japanese guy, in case someone wondering about the meaning will need this in the future.

強く -- adverb form of 強い. interpret as 強い人で

あろう -- volitional of ある. interpret as 存在しよう

"It's from then that I consciously strived to be strong" /"...became aware/conscious of striving/trying to be strong"

Vagabond manga chapter 272 reference
Eng: https://cloud.heavenmanga.org/cdn/2021/02/06/vagabond-chap-272-page-19.jpg

Japanese: https://renote.jp/files/blobs/proxy/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBdGZpIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--e78aa92079c767234ba125ec9e65ef0ac15f733e/d66c0e98.jpg

(the fan translation is wrong. This's what the old lady said

Old lady: "Mahatachi...in this world, there's no such thing as "the strong"

"...There are only those who are striving/trying to be strong... that's all")